# Join 2 tables into 1

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a Customer and Customer_2 table which I am trying to join together:

Both tables have data in them, but upon joining with a statement only the column names are being returned without data. I am trying to use the following join statement:

```
select distinct * 
from Customer c 
join Customer_2 d on c.CUST_NUM = d.CUST_NUM
```

These are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer] 
(
  [CUST_NUM] [INT] NOT NULL,
  [CUST_LNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
  [CUST_FNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
  CUST_BALANCE [MONEY] NOT NULL,
) 
ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Customer_2]  
(
  [CUST_NUM] [INT] NOT NULL,
  [CUST_LNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
  [CUST_FNAME] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data in each Table:

```
INSERT INTO Customer 
VALUES 
('1000', 'Smith', 'Jeanne', '1050.11'),
('1001', 'Ortega', 'Juan', '840.92');

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_2 
VALUES 
('2000', 'McPherson', 'Anne'),
('2001', 'Ortega', 'Juan'),
('2002', 'Kowalski', 'Jan'),
('2003', 'Chan', 'George');
```

Expected output would be combining customer_2 onto the bottom of the customer table with the extra column `CUST_BALANCE` being 0 or null for each of the four customers on the customer 2 table. The desired output should also exclude the second entry for Juan Ortega or where `CUSTOM_NUM` is 2001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL for this operation. ie:

```
select cust_num, cust_fname, cust_lname, balance from Customer
union all 
select cust_num, cust_fname, cust_lname, 0 from Customer_2 c2
where not exists (select * from Customer c 
       where c.cust_fname = c2.cust_fname and c.cust_lname = c2.cust_lname);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b3eeaf0509ddcfadf781c385543d3c3)

PS: Probably it is not an official term but join, joins tables vertically while union [all] joins horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

Just use an full outer join in the 2 tables.

You will get all the rows common and not common from both tables.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: Its usual to provide some code in addition to the description of the solution.